# how to send an custom header to each kind of response the hapi server sends in a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I want to send a custom header specific to a route

the thing is my route handler is as follows :

```
function(req,reply){
   if(req.file) req.file.on('error', reply);
   else {
     if(cond1) reply('OK');
     else if(cond2) reply({obj:obj2});
     else if(cond3) reply(boom.badRequest('Ohhh.. Something wrong'));
     else .. // so many conditions.
  }
}
```

I want to set that custom header only once, not every time i am implementing a condition.

How do i do that?
in hapi docs i could only find to send the headers via chaining or detailed. Both not suitable in this case. As i will have to write same thing again and again in code.

Making common function is ok, but i want something more simpler.
something like this `reply.setHeaderForAllResponseInThisRoute(myHeaderName, value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `reply(value)` gives you a [`response`](http://hapijs.com/api#response-object) object provided `value` is not an error. If it is an error, you get back a Boom object.

The response object has a chainable `header(key. value)` method that you can make use of to do what you need:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        var cond1 = ...;
        var cond2 = ...;
        var cond3 = ...;
        var response;

        if (cond1) {

            // header only applied in this condition

            response = reply(...).header('x-custom-header', 'custom');
        } else if (cond2) {
            response = reply(...);
        } else if (cond3) {
            response = reply(...);
        } else {
            response = reply(...);
        }

        // Headers applied to all responses except errors

        if (!response.isBoom) {
            response.header('x-header-1', 'value1')
                    .header('x-header-2', 'value2');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: not working with boom. `reply(boom.badRequest('message'))` does not have method header. How should i set headers that then?

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer: "Calling `reply(value)` gives you a response object provided value is not an error", `boom.badRequest` returns an error. That's why my code checks that it isn't a boom object.